# configure says guile-config not found

Tags: guile

I am trying to install libgraph on my debian stretch installation. I installed guile and other necessary packages. Also built guile from source. When I try to configure libgraph by using './configure' it says :

`checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
    checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
    checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
    checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
    checking whether build environment is sane... yes
    checking for gawk... gawk
    checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
    checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
    checking for gcc... gcc
    checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
    checking whether the C compiler works... yes
    checking whether we are cross compiling... no
    checking for suffix of executables... 
    checking for suffix of object files... o
    checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
    checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
    checking for gcc option to accept ANSI C... none needed
    checking for style of include used by make... GNU
    checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
    checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
    checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
    checking whether ln -s works... yes
    checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... (cached) yes
    checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
    checking for egrep... grep -E
    checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/ld
    checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
    checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
    checking for BSD-compatible nm... /usr/bin/nm -B
    checking how to recognise dependent libraries... pass_all
    checking for ANSI C header files... yes
    checking for sys/types.h... yes
    checking for sys/stat.h... yes
    checking for stdlib.h... yes
    checking for string.h... yes
    checking for memory.h... yes
    checking for strings.h... yes 
    checking for inttypes.h... yes
    checking for stdint.h... yes
    checking for unistd.h... yes
    checking dlfcn.h usability... yes
    checking dlfcn.h presence... yes
    checking for dlfcn.h... yes
    checking for g++... g++
    checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
    checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
    checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
    checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
    checking for g77... no
    checking for f77... f77
    checking whether we are using the GNU Fortran 77 compiler... yes
    checking whether f77 accepts -g... yes
    checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 32768
    checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
    checking for objdir... .libs
    checking for ar... ar
    checking for ranlib... ranlib
    checking for strip... strip
    checking if gcc static flag  works... yes
    checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
    checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC
    checking if gcc PIC flag -fPIC works... yes
    checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
    checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
    checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
    checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
    checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
    checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
    checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
    checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
    checking whether to build static libraries... yes
    configure: creating libtool
    appending configuration tag "CXX" to libtool
    checking for ld used by g++... /usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64
    checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) is GNU ld... yes
    checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
    checking for g++ option to produce PIC... -fPIC
    checking if g++ PIC flag -fPIC works... yes
    checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... yes
    checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
    checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
    checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
    checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
    appending configuration tag "F77" to libtool
    checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
    checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
    checking whether to build static libraries... yes
    checking for f77 option to produce PIC... -fPIC
    checking if f77 PIC flag -fPIC works... yes
    checking if f77 supports -c -o file.o... yes
    checking whether the f77 linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
    checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so

    checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
    checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
    checking for gawk`... (cached) gawk
    checking for sdl-config... /usr/bin/sdl-config
    checking for SDL - version >= 1.2.0... yes
    checking SDL  ==>  SDL_image library... SDL_image = yes
    checking for Guile... ./configure: line 19637: guile-config: command not found
    configure: cannot find guile-config; is Guile installed?

I also tried : 
`ls -l /usr/bin/guile-config`

but it says : `ls: cannot access '/usr/bin/guile-config': No such file or directory`

Comment: installing guile-2.0-dev did the configuration but now make says libguile.h not found

Comment: what operating system or distro?

Answer (score 2):

Please install the guile-dev package.
 Installation instructions depend on your operating system. Assuming you're on Linux, you can search for `guile-dev` in the graphical package manager (e g. YaST for SuSE, aptitude and friends for Ubuntu, etc.). Or, just search online for the package.

Comment: found guile-2.0-dev.

Comment: `apt-cache search guile-dev` on Ubuntu 18.04 shows `guile-2.0-dev - Development files for Guile 2.0`. So that is likely the current version.

Comment: You use `guile-config compile` to determine, or to specify, the location of header (.h) files. Type `guile-config` for more information.