# guile-config fails to run

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, guile, ubuntu-20.04

I am trying to install libgraph in my WSL Ubuntu 20.04 installation. I installed all the necessary packages. But when I try to configure libgraph, it fails with this:

```
$ ./configure
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... sleep: cannot read realtime clock: Invalid argument
yes
.
.
.
.
.
checking for gawk... (cached) gawk
checking for sdl-config... /usr/bin/sdl-config
checking for SDL - version >= 1.2.0... yes
checking SDL  ==>  SDL_image library... SDL_image = yes
checking for Guile... Wrong __data_start/_end pair
./configure: line 19582:  7444 Aborted                 (core dumped) guile-config link > /dev/null
configure: cannot find guile-config; is Guile installed?
```

I installed guile-dev too. From https://stackoverflow.com/a/53095838/4791142

I tried installing different versions of guile(and guile-dev), namely 2.0, 2.2, and 3.0. But nothing seems to work.

In every case, guile-config fails to run like this:

```
$ guile-config
Wrong __data_start/_end pair
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems you need a newer version of guile: https://github.com/weechat/weechat/issues/988 or more particularly, of boehm gc library: https://github.com/rdp/ffmpeg-windows-build-helpers/issues/452#issuecomment-638639182

Comment: Is this problem due to WSL or Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: Either WSL or boehm libgc not sure which...or possibly debian for not publishing an updated libgc package for years...